# REGEXREPLACE all characters until at least 4 consecutive capital letters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a very long string, I'd like to remove everything that starts with `SPAIN:`  until we get at least 4 capital letters in a row ending with a `:`  (ie. `INDIA:`  or `SOUTH AFRICA:`  or `NORTHERN-IRELAND:` ).

My attempt where A2 is the very long string:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"SPAIN: .*([A-ZÀ-ÿ\-\' ]{4,}): ","$1: ")
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't work as it's erasing everything until the very last 4 capital letters in the string.

Any ideas?

Sheet example to play with here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_DbCmGhqaDvFtdi20PnuA35i-Sv_3nMS9Kl_e7CVu3k/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"SPAIN:([^:]+)([^A-Z:])","$2: ")
```

[image]

For sample sheet will work following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"ESPAGNE:(.*?)-:-([A-Z]|$)","$2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Basic, thanks for your answer. I also have special characters in between the countries (such as `: - ' / . ( )`). Any ideas?

Comment: @Exdefoot added formula for sample sheet,

Comment: the second formula is pretty much what was looking for, thanks. Only one last issue is if I have twice (or more) `ESPAGNE: ` in my string, it removes only the first one. Is there a way, in one `REGEXREPLACE` to remove all of them?

Comment: @Exdefoot that is weird. As I test, formula removes all occurencies of found strings. Do you have a test case?

Comment: you will find an example on line 7 of the document

Comment: @Exdefoot there are two consecutive ```ESPAGNE``` - for that use ```=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"(ESPAGNE:(.*?)-:-)+([A-Z]|$)","$3"))```

Comment: Thanks @basic that's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I have added a new sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet. The following formula is in B2 of that sheet:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,IF(LEFT(A2:A,4)="ESPA","^.+("&REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"-:-([A-ZÀ-Ý]{4}[^:]+)")&")","ESPAGNE[^~]+-:-([A-ZÀ-Ý]{4}[^:]+)"),"$1"),"ESPA.+$","")))`

This retrieves the correct result for all of the cases in your sample.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I'm looking for something that can be done in only one REGEXREPLACE, pretty much like @basic 's solution